# Javascript Queries for RubyOnRails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to subtract the j[3] value into selling_price text field and show result in profit/loss field,but it working in a first row of the page only, next row didn't calculate perfectly.

```js
<script>
    function sm() {
      var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
      var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) - parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue);
       if(!isNaN(result))  {
      document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
}
}
</script>
```

```html
<%= form_for ProductionReport.new ,:url=>{:controller=>"users",:action=>"rate_per_unit_report" } do |i| %>
<% $rpu = @arr.sort_by{|i| i[1].to_i}.reverse%>
<% @arr.each do |j| %>
<tr>
<td><%=j[0]%></td>
<td><%=j[1]%></td>
<td><%=j[2]%></td>
<%@q=j[3]%>
<td><%=i.text_field j[3],:value=>@q,:id=>"txt1",:onkeyup=>"sm()",:class=>"txt",:readonly =>true%></td>
<td><%= i.text_field :selling_price,:id=>"txt2",:onkeyup=>"sm()",:class=>"txt"%></td>
<td><%= i.text_field :profit_loss,:id=>"txt3",:class=>"txt",:readonly =>true %></td>
<%end%>
<%end%>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>total</td>
<td><%=@total%></td>
<td><%=@total1%></td>
<td><%=@total2%></td>

Answer me........
```

Comment: can you use jquery ?

Comment: There are problem because you create fields in loop with same ids, you have to create dynamic ids

Answer (score 0):

simple solution if you can use jquery:

Just change this:

```
<td><%=i.text_field j[3],:value=>@q,:id=>"txt1",:onkeyup=>"sm()",:class=>"txt",:readonly =>true%></td>
<td><%= i.text_field :selling_price,:id=>"txt2",:onkeyup=>"sm()",:class=>"txt"%></td>
<td><%= i.text_field :profit_loss,:id=>"txt3",:class=>"txt",:readonly =>true %></td>
```

to this:

```
<td><%=i.text_field j[3],:value=>@q,:id=>"txt1",:onkeyup=>"sm()",:class=>"txt text1",:readonly =>true%></td>
<td><%= i.text_field :selling_price,:id=>"txt2",:onkeyup=>"sm()",:class=>"txt text2"%></td>
<td><%= i.text_field :profit_loss,:id=>"txt3",:class=>"txt text3",:readonly =>true %></td>
```

and change sm function to:

```
<script>
        function sm() {
          var txtFirstNumberValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('.text1').val();
          var txtSecondNumberValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('.text2').val();
          var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) - parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue);
           if(!isNaN(result))  {
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.text3').val(result);
    }
    }
    </script>
```